# How to find out when Google chrome remembered a login name

Tags: windows, google-chrome

Google chrome remembers an email addresses when somebody uses it to log in.  Is it possible to find out when the email address was recorded?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check Google Chrome database in :

C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases

if you are using Windows Vista or later

C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Application Support\Google\Chrome\Default\databases

if you are using Windows XP

You will need to download SQLite to open it